# A formula involving the heat kernel on the universal cover of a punctured plane

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, isospectrality

I am looking for the earliest reference to the following formula:
$$
\int_0^\infty\tilde{P}(1,e^{i\alpha},t)\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{1}{\pi \alpha^2},\quad \alpha>0,
$$
where $\tilde{P}(x,y,t)$ is the heat kernel on the universal cover of the punctured plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

This formula was proven [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.08941) (Lemma 6.1) using conformal invariance of the Brownian loop measure, and it can be used to give a simple derivation of the value of the $\zeta_\Omega(0),$ where $\zeta_\Omega$ is the spectral zeta-function and $\Omega$ is a polygon or a Euclidean surface with conical singularities. The computation of these values is due to Cheeger (Spectral geometry of singular Riemannian spaces, J. Diff. Geom., 18  (1983), 575-657), and, in a particular case and in a less explicit form, to  M. Kac in the "Can one hear the shape of a drum?" paper.

It looks likely that the above formula might have appeared in the literature before, however, I was unable to locate it. Any hints?